# iOS Safari suggests "phishing" when passing username:password to @url

Tags: basic-authentication, phishing

Passing a username and a password for **Basic Authentication** is comfortable; But not if iOS Safari tells me to stay away from my website every time.

**Example URL**

> http://bytecode77:123456@example-subdomain.bytecode77.com

Is there anything I can change in my code or webserver configuration to avoid such suspiciousness?

[image: phishing warning]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, user credentials in URLs have been removed for security reasons
and no longer appear in the
[protocol specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2).
I read that Chrome and IE do not support that at all anymore.

Comment: A deprecated pattern? Would it be equal safe to add those in the `GET` parameters?

Comment: It is not ideal as I'm afraid they would be saved in the browser history, servers logs and the such. If you have to do it at least use https which is encrypted, so only the client and server machines will store the credentials. Look up the authentication header for a better place to keep them

Comment: @Rad80 Credentials **are** sent via authentication headers when they're put in the URL.  The browser deals with parsing the URL and sends the appropriate request header.  It isn't going to turn up in a server log any differently than if someone was prompted for a username/password and typed it in.

Comment: @Brad I was replying to the comment that was about putting credentials in the query part of the URL rather than using basic http auth.

Comment: @Rad80 If you use the format `https://user:pass@example.com`, then `user:pass` will be base-64 encoded and sent as basic auth in the `Authorization` header.

Comment: @Brad Yes, I know.

Comment: @Brad seems like using `https` doesn't help anymore. It works in Safari 10 but doesn't work in Safari 11 & 12.

Comment: Way to go, Apple.  :-(