# Why won't this URL work in Safari?

Tags: safari

This works in Chrome and Firefox and IE, but not Safari on OSX. Any way to get around it?

"There is no application set to open the URL username:password@www.example.com."

http://username:password@www.example.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Safari suggests "phishing" when passing username:password to @url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971092/ios-safari-suggests-phishing-when-passing-usernamepassword-to-url)

Comment: I have the same issue, in URL credentials works on Safari 10 but doesn't work for on 11 and 12 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `http://username:password@www.example.com` instead. `http://` goes first.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator

`scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id`

Comment: This gives the same result in OSX Safari "There is no application set to open the URL username:password@www.example.com."

Comment: It works for me (but presents a phishing warning) with `https://username:password@google.com/` but not `http://username:password@google.com/`. Guessing it's a security setting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971092/ios-safari-suggests-phishing-when-passing-usernamepassword-to-url suggests "user credentials in URLs have been removed for security reasons"