# iOS 11 Safari: How to pass user/password in URL for HTTP Basic Authentication?

Tags: ios, authentication, passwords, mobile-safari

In front of me, I have one iPhone running iOS 9 and another iPhone running iOS 11.

On the iOS 9 iPhone, I can navigate to http://username:password@mywebsite.com in Safari, and the webpage will pull up without asking for my username and password. I can then add this full URL to my Home Screen as a direct shortcut.

On the iOS 11 iPhone, when I navigate to http://username:password@mywebsite.com, I am automatically redirected to http://mywebsite.com. I have to manually type my username and password in the pop-up form, no matter what. I cannot add http://username:password@mywebsite.com to my Home Screen because the URL is always changed to http://mywebsite.com. It seems that there is no way to edit or customize the URL of a Home Screen shortcut.

For my iOS 11 iPhone, is it possible to embed my website's username and password in the URL itself, so that I can add this URL to my iPhone's Home Screen, so I will never need to type in my username and password manually?

I understand that embedding the password in the URL may not be very safe, but this is not a "high security" application, so convenience is more important than high security in this case.

I read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45286/184907) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/23420/184907) for help but did not find an answer that worked for iOS 11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971092/ios-safari-suggests-phishing-when-passing-usernamepassword-to-url no luck here either